# how to do an api chain call in axios

Tags: javascript, api, axios, chain

im new to axios, i need to get the result of all artists and then each artist has api url for cover, albums, and artist info.
So can some one explain me how do i do a chain request in this api call:

```
    "result": [
        {
            "id_artist": 70170,
            "artist": "Ameritz Karaoke Crew",
            "cover": "https://api.happi.dev//v1/music/cover/70170/artist",
            "api_artist": "https://api.happi.dev/v1/music/artists/70170",
            "api_albums": "https://api.happi.dev/v1/music/artists/70170/albums"
        },
```

Answer (score 0):

I aimed to create a function that takes on item from your result and populate the `cover`, `api_artist` and `api_albums` properties with their respective data.

So here `populateArtistWithApiData` takes an `artist` object, makes the necessary requests and populate the object.

`Promise.all` allows me to wait for all the requests for all the artists to be done before resolving an array of populated artists.

```js
function populateArtistWithApiData(artist) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    Promise
      .all([
        axios.get(artist.cover),
        axios.get(artist.api_artist),
        axios.get(artist.api_albums),
      ])
      .then(([cover, api_artist, api_albums]) => {
        artist.cover = cover;
        artist.api_artist = api_artist;
        artist.api_albums = api_albums;

        resolve(artist);
      });
  });
}

Promise.all(result.map((artist) => populateArtistWithApiData(artist))).then(
  (populatedArtists) => {
    // There you have the same `artist` objects as before with the properties `cover`,
    // `api_artist`, `api_albums` populated with the data
  }
);
```

Comment: Hello, sorry for the late reply and thanks to help me on this, but i still have a doubt, does this means that it will catch the respective artist id and associate to the respective API url??

Comment: It will replace the URLs in your objects by the actual result of fetching those URLs.